# In Flex DataGrid, How to use ArrayCollection as a dataProvider for a XML file?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid

I create a DataGrid to display a XML file and I have used XMLListCollection before. But when I modified the XML file, the DataGrid does NOT refresh itself automatically. I googled for this problem and found these links:

[refresh flex dataGrid](http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2008/10/refresh-flex-datagrid.html)

[refresh/reload a dataGrid in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112018/refresh-reload-a-datagrid-in-flex)

I realize I should use an ArrayCollection as a dataProvider and make it bindable. Then I can use `myDataGrid.invalidateDisplayList()` to solve the "refresh" problem.

But I have a new problem: I want the dataGrid to display like this:

```
"Jonathan"
```

But since I use the ArrayCollection, it displays like this:

```
<firstName>Jonathan</firstName>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The best to do is to convert your XML as soon as you can into objects stored in a bindable ArrayCollection. This way, you won't have to deal with such issues. BUT if you don't want to, you can implement a custom renderer or simply set a custom labelfunction to you datagrid.